# How can I make sure that other functions is run after this get function is fully completed and rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that adds elements with data by a get json function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        ADD.Listitem.get();
        });
```

It basicly adds a bunch of html tags with data etc. The problem I have is following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    ADD.Listitem.get();

    var arr = [];
    $(".Listitem-section-item-title").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this.text()));
    });
 });
```

-

```
get: function(web) {
            AST.Utils.JSON.get("/_vti_bin/AST/ListItem/ListitemService.svc/GetListItem", null, AST.Listitem.renderListitem);
        },
renderListitem: function(data) {
            $("#Listitem-template").tmpl(data["ListItemResults"]).prependTo(".ListItem-section-template");
    }
```

and here is the json get:

```
ADD.Utils.JSON.get = function (url, data, onSuccess) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: ADD.Utils.JSON.error,
        converters: { "text json": ADD.Utils.JSON.deserialize }
    });
}
```

The array each loop is not running beacuse  the get method is not finished with rendering the `Listitem-section-item-title` selector so it cant find the selector.

Is there any good solutions for this?

Comment: If `get()` is asynchronous (as it seems to be), it should either take a callback argument or return a promise. Are you the author of that function?

Comment: Do you mean that `get` is asynchronous ? Then it probably accepts a callback or returns a promise *[edit : damn, Frédéric was faster... At least it's visible I agree :) ]*.

Comment: You could place the Ajax code into the $(document).ready() function and then place your extra code into the Success function of the Ajax call.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes I will post it in second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your functions to return the promise given by `$.ajax` :

```
ADD.Utils.JSON.get = function (url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        converters: { "text json": ADD.Utils.JSON.deserialize }
    }).fail(ADD.Utils.JSON.error);
}

get: function(web) {
    return AST.Utils.JSON.get("/_vti_bin/AST/ListItem/ListitemService.svc/GetListItem", null).done(AST.Listitem.renderListitem);
},
```

So that you can do

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    ADD.Listitems.get().done(function(){
        var arr = [];
        $(".Listitem-section-item-title").each(function() {
            arr.push($(this.text()));
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why?

Comment: There are two functions to modify to return the promise. The one I showed (`ADD.Utils.JSON.get`) and your `ADD.Listitem.get` (that I let as an exercise).

Comment: Its still not working the .each() runs before the get method is completed. What I added was return ICC.Utils.JSON.get(....) at get: function() and now im not receiving the "Cannot call method 'done'". About the ADD.Listitem.get I dont think I am suppose to add something inside the parameter could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

**Callback:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ADD.Listitem.get(url,data,function(){
   var arr = [];
   $(".Listitem-section-item-title").each(function() {
     arr.push($(this.text()));
   });
 });
});
```

**Without callback:**

If you cant get the get method to take a callback or return a promise then I think the best way will be to check when its done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  ADD.Listitem.get();

  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if ($("#thingWhichShouldExist").length>0){
      var arr = [];
      $(".Listitem-section-item-title").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this.text()));
      });
    clearInterval(timer);
    }
  },50);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Retrieve the values and on success, call a function which will push the values into the array.

Also, `arr.push($(this.text()));` should be `arr.push($(this).text());`.